# Filtering a collectionView with a searchBar from a RxSwift Variable

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, rx-swift

I've just started implementing RxSwift.

I've got the following function to dynamically fill a collectionView with users returned from a Firebase observe call, but I'm struggling to then dynamically filter the users based on any potential entires in the searchBar.

Rx collectionView binding:

```
private func bind() {
    viewModel.users.asObservable()
        .bind(to: nearbyCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "NearbyCell", cellType: NearbyCell.self)) {
            row, user, cell in
            cell.configureCell(user: user)
        }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
}
```

Should I return to the default collectionView implementations and simply use Rx to dynamically update the collectionView objects, or is there a better way to do this?

My old implementation used the following:

```
            if self.viewModel.inSearchMode {
            user = self.viewModel.filteredUsers[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(user: user)
        } else {
            user = self.viewModel.users[indexPath.row]
            cell.configureCell(user: user)
        }
```

Thanks a lot for any help!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use combineLatest to filter them out

```
let searchString = searchTextField.rx.text
let filteredUsersObservable = Observable.combineLatest(searchString, viewModel.users, resultSelector: { string, users in
            return users.filter { $0 == string }
        })

filteredUsersObservable
    .bind(to: nearbyCollectionView.rx.items(cellIdentifier: "NearbyCell", cellType: NearbyCell.self)) {
        row, user, cell in
        cell.configureCell(user: user)
    }.disposed(by: disposeBag)
```

I'm not sure if the syntax fully correct, but the idea is to get the signal every time there's a change on the text field, make it as an observable and filter with the users observable.

Comment: With a couple of amendments this was perfect. Thanks a lot for the help!